# POI not writing into second column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
if ((found.equals("found in label") || foundlabelcol.equals("found in labelcol"))) {
        XSSFRow rowwriter = sheet1.createRow(b + 1);
        XSSFCell cellwriter = rowwriter.createCell(2);
        cellwriter.setCellType(cellwriter.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cellwriter.setCellValue(cellinput[b]);
                //This one works fine.

        XSSFCell cellwriterfound = rowwriter.createCell(3);
        cellwriterfound.setCellType(cellwriterfound.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cellwriterfound.setCellValue("Match found in NOAH");
        //This one doesn't write.                                           
    } else if ((found.equals("Not found in label") || foundlabelcol.equals("Not found in labelcol"))) {
        XSSFRow rowwriter1 = sheet1.createRow(b + 1);
        XSSFCell cellwriter1 = rowwriter1.createCell(2);
        cellwriter1.setCellType(cellwriter1.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cellwriter1.setCellValue(cellinput[b]);
        //This one works fine.

        XSSFCell cellwriterfound1 = rowwriter1.createCell(3);
        cellwriterfound1.setCellType(cellwriterfound1.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cellwriterfound1.setCellValue("No Match in NOAH");
        //This one doesn't write.                                           
    }
```

It is only writing the output in column A and no data in the second column (b), **I want column A and column B to be populated with respective results but only column A is populated. what am I missing here?**

[image]

Comment: What are the expected results? Is the code overwriting column A? Is it not writing anything for column B?

Comment: @andrewdleach  it is not overwriting column A but column B is always blank. and it is suppose to have data in both the columns, for ex: Row 8 should read `Main City` in `column A` and `Match found` in `column B`, hope this helps. thank you.

Comment: Are you using the org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet? I remember when I wrote an app with POI I had to specify the Object all the way down the directory trail...Otherwise, the default is some weird swing package I think

Comment: `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\migration.xlsx");
  XSSFWorkbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook();
  XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb1.createSheet();`

Comment: Are you writing to a non blank workbook?

Comment: @andrewdleach yes when i run the test case first time, but than it overwrites the same file everytime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82233/discussion-between-t-rex-the-1st-break-dancer-and-andrewdleach).

Comment: This was my bad, i was writing the output on the wrong file out of the 2 that i was using, thank you everyone for you help. @andrewdleach really helped in nailing the issue.